# Ruby on Rails Titleize Underscore,Hyphenated and Single Quote Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails titleize method removes hyphen and underscore, and capitalize method does not capitalize the word comes after hyphen and underscore. I wanted to do something like following:

```
sam-joe denis-moore      → Sam-Joe Denis-Moore
sam-louise o'donnell     → Sam-Louise O'Donnell
arthur_campbell john-foo → Arthur_Campbell John-Foo"
```

What is pattern that need to use on gsub below for this:

```
"sam-joe denis-moore".humanize.gsub(??) { $1.capitalize }
# => "Sam-Joe Denis-Moore"
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: You should take a look at http://rubular.com -- let's you test out regular expressions for Ruby programs.

Comment: @Hunter Stevens I will try my best but I am not so good in regex :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_string.split(/([ _-])/).map(&:capitalize).join
```

You can put whatever delimiters you like in the regex. I used , `_`, and `-`. So, for example:

```
'sam-joe denis-moore'.split(/([ _-])/).map(&:capitalize).join
```

Results in:

```
'Sam-Joe Denis-Moore'
```

What it does is:

1. `.split(/([ _-])/)` splits the string into an array of substrings at the given delimiters, and keeps the delimiters as substrings
2. `.map(&:capitalize)` maps the resulting array of strings to a new array of strings, capitalizing each string in the array (delimiters, when capitalized, are unaffected)
3. `.join` joins the resulting array of substrings back together for the final result

You could, if you want, monkey patch the `String` class with your own `titleize`:

```
class String
  def my_titleize
    self.split(/([ _-])/).map(&:capitalize).join
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
'sam-joe denis-moore'.my_titleize
=> 'Sam-Joe Denis-Moore'
```

Comment: Thanks @lurker  for quick response and it works as charm.And also really appreciated for explaining how it works.

Answer (score 1):

While lurker's answer works, it's far more complicated than it needs to be. As you surmised, you can do this with `gsub` alone:

```
INITIAL_LETTER_EXPR = /(?:\b|_)[a-z]/

arr = [ "sam-joe denis-moore",
        "sam-louise o'donnell",
        "arthur_campbell john-foo" ]

arr.each do |str|
  puts str.gsub(INITIAL_LETTER_EXPR) { $&.upcase }
end

# => Sam-Joe Denis-Moore
#    Sam-Louise O'Donnell
#    Arthur_Campbell John-Foo
```